# PascalPrecht angular-translate useUrlLoader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm new to both programming and angular. I need to use angular-translate with its' useUrlLoader, since my translations are stored in database. `$translateProvider.useUrlLoader('foo/bar.json');
 $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');`

While using staticFilesLoader seems enough simple for me, since I need just two separate json files with translation data, i can't get what useUrlLoader expects. As far as I understand, it expects json which includes multiply language translations (both English and German for example).
Can't find example of such file anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The StaticFilesLoader expects that you store all translations for different languages in separate files on the server. It makes requests like this:

```
/your/server/i18n/locale-en.json
/your/server/i18n/locale-de.json
/your/server/i18n/locale-fr.json
```

where `/your/server/i18n/locale-` and `.json` are *prefix* and *suffix* (respectively) which you've passed during configuration.

The UrlLoader expects that you have one "clever" endpoint instead of a bunch of files. It makes requests like this:

```
/your/server/i18n/locale-endpoint?lang=en
/your/server/i18n/locale-endpoint?lang=de
/your/server/i18n/locale-endpoint?lang=fr
```

where `/your/server/i18n/locale-endpoint` and `lang` are *url* and *queryParameter* (respectively) which you've passed during configuration. The *url* is required, but *queryParameter* may be omitted (defaults to "lang").

You can setup the UrlLoader either like this:

```
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader('/path/to/your/endpoint', {
  queryParameter : 'localeKey'
});
```

or like this:

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translateUrlLoader', {
  url : '/path/to/your/endpoint',
  queryParameter : 'localeKey'
});
```

Both loaders expect to load translation as JSON object. It could look like this:

```
{
  "translationId" : "Translation for this ID",
  "anotherTranslationId": "Another translation for another id"
}
```

You can find more information about different loaders in [the official guide](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/12_asynchronous-loading).

A source code of the UrlLoader can be found in [the angular-translate repository](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/master/src/service/loader-url.js).

Hope, this helps.

Comment: I switched to other project, where multi-languages weren't in need. It was awesome to find this answer here today, when I need them again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi @DWand I need to pass more variables than url and queryParameter for my backend, any advice?

Comment: Hi, @razorblade. In this case I'd recommend you to create a custom loader. Probably, it could be based on some built-in loader. In this case you'll be able to manipulate with URLs any way you like.

Comment: This gives `Error: [$injector:unpr]`. Any suggestions to fix this?